# Where do I pick up from after finishing the Deltora Quest anime?

Tags: deltora-quest

I think that I am not the only one that watched Deltora Quest anime (or should we say TV Show, doesn't matter).

I watched it once, a long time ago, on TV, when I didn't have internet. It was a lot of fun and holds a lot of memories.

The thing is, I watched it again around year ago, and I almost cried of happiness when I saw that's line of books, and there's a lot more to it.

Where can I read those books online ? I want to know what happened after the TV show. Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

The first 8 books were adapted into a 52+13 episode series by OLM.

Please note that the 13 episodes after the 52 episodes are original and not part of the original novels.

The *[Deltora Shadowlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_2)* (3 books) and *[Dragons of Deltora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_3)* (4 books) series are where you can continue from. Depending on your location, you may order them from online book distributors (in physical or e-book format) or see if they are available in your local library in electronic format.

Comment: Hm, sounds ok, but you think there aren't any online versions ? I don't think that we have that in Bosnia and Herzegovina :(

Comment: No, legal sources besides ebooks or audiobooks.